# How can I create a JSON structure dynamically from Go?

Tags: json, go

As in, serializing JSON.

My current code doesn't work, and I think it must have something to do with the fact that _Map, _String, etc. are not public.

```
// vim:ft=go:ts=2

package main

import "json"
import "fmt"
import vector "container/vector"

func main() {
  groceries := vector.New(0);
  groceries.Push(&json._String{s:"Eggs"});
  groceries.Push(&json._String{s:"Bread"});
  groceries.Push(&json._String{s:"Milk"});
  var tree json.Json = &json._Map{m:map[string]json.Json{
    "hello": &json._String{s:"world"},
    "groceries": &json._Array{a:groceries}
  }};
  fmt.Printf(json.JsonToString(tree));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation at http://golang.org/pkg/json/ ? The underscored identifiers are not exported.

Comment: @devyn - the highlighting syntax is based on a fixed coding standard, which is probably a union of C# and Java.

Comment: remember how classes are named? Capital letters go first.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) looks promising.

```
//import "github.com/Jeffail/gabs"

jsonObj := gabs.New()
// or gabs.Consume(jsonObject) to work on an existing map[string]interface{}

jsonObj.Set(10, "outter", "inner", "value")
jsonObj.SetP(20, "outter.inner.value2")
jsonObj.Set(30, "outter", "inner2", "value3")

fmt.Println(jsonObj.String())

// Prints
// {"outter":{"inner":{"value":10,"value2":20},"inner2":{"value3":30}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the TestJsonMap function in $GOROOT/src/pkg/json/generic_test.go, it seems to do something similar to what you want. The relevant code is

```
var jsontests = []string{
    `null`,
    `true`,
    `false`,
    `"abc"` // , etc.
}
values := make(map[string]Json);
mapstr := "{";
for i := 0; i < len(jsontests); i++ {
    val, ok, errtok := StringToJson(jsontests[i]);
    if !ok {
        t.Errorf("StringToJson(%#q) => error near %v", jsontests[i], errtok)
    }
    if i > 0 {
        mapstr += ","
    }
    values[jsontests[i]] = val;
    mapstr += Quote(jsontests[i]);
    mapstr += ":";
    mapstr += JsonToString(val);
}
mapstr += "}";

mapv, ok, errtok := StringToJson(mapstr);
```

You want to push the value "world" onto the name "hello" and ["Eggs","Bread","Milk"] onto "Groceries". Try

```
var values = make(map[string]string);
values["hello"] = `"world"`;
values["groceries"] = `["Eggs","Bread","Milk"]`;

mapstr := "{";
needcomma := false;
for key,val := range values {
    jsonval, ok, errtok := json.StringToJson(val);
    // Check errors

    // Add a comma
    if needcomma == true {
        mapstr += ",";
    } else {
        needcomma = true;
    } 

    mapstr += json.Quote(key);
    mapstr += ":";
    mapstr += json.JsonToString(jsonval);
}
mapstr += "}";
mapv, ok, errtok := json.StringToJson(mapstr);
```

Comment: Scott, first of all this is part of the JSON package, so it won't compile without alteration. Secondly, it seems to be taking strings and testing the parser against them. I don't think this is what the original poster is asking about at all. devyn seems to want to create JSON from a data structure.

Comment: I added an example of how that snippet can be used. If necessary the groceries array could be easily built from a []string.

Comment: Very interesting, but what I really want to do is create a JSON string completely dynamically, e.g. for a JSON-RPC server?

Comment: I may just end up building my own JSON serialization library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bare bones of an implementation of the interface for `Json`:

```
package main
import {"json"; "fmt"; "os";}
type MyTest struct { MyMap map[string]string;}
func (t * MyTest) Kind()    int       { return json.MapKind  } 
func (t * MyTest) Len()     int       { return len (t.MyMap) }
func (t * MyTest) Number()  float64   { return 0 }
func (t * MyTest) Bool()    bool      { return false }
func (t * MyTest) Elem(int) json.Json { return json.Null }
func (t * MyTest) String() (s string) {
    s = "{"; 
    count := 0;
    for key, value := range t.MyMap {
        s += json.Quote(key) + ":" + json.Quote(value);
        count++;
        if (count < len (t.MyMap)) {
            s += ",";
        }
    }
    s += "}";
    return;
}
func (t * MyTest) Get(s string) json.Json {
    j, ok, errtok := json.StringToJson (t.MyMap[s]);
    if ! ok {
        fmt.Printf ("Fail at %s\n", errtok);
        os.Exit (1);
    }
    return j;
}
```

Here is some testing code:

```
func main () {
    var megaburger = new (MyTest);
    megaburger.MyMap = make(map[string]string);
    megaburger.MyMap["frog"] = "toad";
    megaburger.MyMap["captain"] = "kirk";
    megaburger.MyMap["laser"] = "phaser";
    fmt.Println (megaburger.Kind());
    fmt.Println (megaburger.Len());
    fmt.Println (json.JsonToString (megaburger));
}
```

This puts a JsonToString method onto the type `MyTest` by defining the interface for the Json package. Clearly this doesn't do anything interesting yet, but you could define various things like these for your particular data structure in order to have a "JSON-izer" which created whatever JSON you liked from your structure. There is a nice example of how to do [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) using something called `_Null` in the library source code file `generic.go`.